# Convert a mixin that accepts only from & to keyframe selectors to accept multiple keyframe selectors

Tags: css, less, css-animations, mixins, less-mixins

I have this Less mixin:

```
.keyframes (@name, @fromRules, @toRules) {
    @-webkit-keyframes ~'@{name}' { from { @fromRules(); } to { @toRules(); } }
            @keyframes ~'@{name}' { from { @fromRules(); } to { @toRules(); } }
}
```

I call for example:

```
.keyframes(fade-in,
    {
        opacity: 0;
    },
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
);
```

The result is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

But how can I use Less mixins so I can use keyframes-selector different from 0%, 100% and also more than 2 keyframes-selector so result will look like this:

```
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just remove the from and to rules from the mixin and pass the entire rule (with all ther percentage splits) as one param to the mixin.

Comment: Or have multiple mixins, 1 for the 2 stage, and another 1 for the 3 stage

Comment: You can see here a [basic sample](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/kKqHG).

Comment: Btw., also note that you don't need `~""` stuff there. Just `@name` is an absolutey correct syntax there.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is better solution. My was unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @Harry please add your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @quarky: Are you looking for anything extra mate? I hope the answer addressed your question fully.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by passing the rules for the entire list of keyframe selectors (like `0%`, `50%`, `100%` etc) as a single rule-set to the mixin along with the name of the animation.

Also as mentioned by seven-phases-max in the comments, `@-webkit-keyframes ~'@{name}'` is not required and it can simply be written as `@-webkit-keyframes @name`.

```
.keyframes (@name, @rules) {
    @-webkit-keyframes @name { @rules(); }
            @keyframes @name { @rules(); }
}

div{
    .keyframes(fade-in,
    {
        0% { opacity: 0;}
        50% { opacity: 1;}
        100% { opacity: 0;}
    });
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/kKqHG) - Click on the eye icon in the CSS box to see the compiled output.

**Note:**

- [Passing rulesets to a mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) was introduced in Less v1.7.0 and hence the above code will not work with lower versions.